# social networking post is not getting sent to the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am trying to create a social networking news feed, the post that the user enters does not appear in my database, I think this is because of the post button because when I click on it nothing seems to happen, any help or suggestion would be mostly appreciated.

Comment: remove this onclick ="javascript:send_post()" from form submit button , and add onsubmit="return send_post()" in <form> tag

Comment: This still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

From your code(the one before 5th revision),
`document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;`
You don't have a field with id ="status", which can cause javascript erroe "Uncaught TypeError".